# Cheker to clean a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a small script with jquery, I'd like, that by clicking on the checkbox, I'll take the first textarea and pass it to the 2 text area without numbers, but, that textarea 1 will be as it is in 2

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
      function validate() {
          if (document.getElementById('cheker').checked) {

              results = document.getElementById("all").value;
              final = results.string.replace(/\d+/g, '');
              document.getElementById("filtrado").value(final);

          } else {

          }
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="all"></textarea>
<input id="checker" name="checker1" type="checkbox" />
<textarea id="filtrado"></textarea>
```

Comment: `value` is not a function but a property. And please declare the variables. And you cant synchronously handle an asynchronous event like a click. Have a look how event handlers work

Comment: value is not a method....

Comment: Change `.value(final)` to `.value = final`

Answer (score 0):

`"value"` is a property , as mentioned by jonas and you have a wrong in id `"cheker > checker"` , try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        function validate() {
            if (document.getElementById('checker').checked) {
                results = document.getElementById("all").value;
                final = results.replace(/\d+/g, '');

                document.getElementById("filtrado").value = final;

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried, still doing the same

Comment: @Nicole How are you calling it? Because there's nothing wrong with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call `string` on a variable that is already a `string`, that and some typos and [LGSon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326846/cheker-to-clean-a-string/49327325#comment85655708_49326846), try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function validate() {
                if (document.getElementById('checker').checked) {

                    results = document.getElementById("all").value;
                    final = results.replace(/\d+/g, '');
                    document.getElementById("filtrado").value=final;

                } else {

                }
            }
            $('#checker').change(function(){
            validate()
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea id="all"></textarea>
    <input id="checker" name="checker1" type="checkbox" />
    <textarea id="filtrado"></textarea>

</body>

</html>
```